# How can I open a file based on a file name specified by user input?

Tags: c++, fstream

I want to make a simple program that will allow the user to create/open files and add text to them.  This is the code I have currently:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter file name:" << endl;
    char fileName;
    cin >> fileName;
    ofstream myFile;
    myFile.open(fileName, ios::out);
    myFile << "This is the file text.\n";
    myFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I receive the following error at `myFile.open(fileName, ios::out)`:

> error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::open(std::__cxx11::string&, const openmode&)'

Comment: fileName should be string

Comment: It would not be that interesting to only allow 1 character filenames..

Comment: I've updated my answer. Check it below and tell me whether it works.

Comment: This works now thanks.

Comment: Could you accept my answer if it worked :-)

Answer (score 2):

The simple problem you are having here is that the variable `filename` that stores the name of the file is of type `char`. Change it to `string` so that it works.

On another note, try to break down the error message you got:

> `no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream::open(std::__cxx11::string&, const openmode&)'`

In `open(std::__cxx11::string& ...` it clearly says that the data type of the file name should be `string&`. This indicated that you had a data type error, which is true because you have used `char` instead of `string`.

Another thing: use char only when you want to accept a single letter as input; when you want to take a word or a sentence, store it in a string variable, and get it from the user using the `getline()` function. This will make your life easier.

---

To modify your code, firstly change your variable declaration statement to:

```
    string fileName; // std:: is not required as you have the line "using namespace std"
```

Secondly, change the input statement of the file name from `cin >> filename;` to:

```
    getline(cin, fileName);
```

It should work after these changes.

---

EDIT: I found the peoblem to your question. You will nave to change the open command to:

```
myFile.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::out);
```

Like it says in the error, the function needs a string passed to ot, however, when we take the string as input and store it in the variable fileName, it simply converts the string into a const char *. This is invisible to you when you run the code, but every once in a while, it causes an error.

This should definitely work now.

Comment: I've made these changes and still am getting an error where I try to open the file ("myFile.open(fileName, ios:: out);).  I've tried replacing fileName with "wfldfl" an this ran properly.

Comment: ***and still am getting an error where*** No one can help unless you specify the exact text of the error message.

Comment: Agree with @drescherjm. Specify what the error message says, and which line the error message came from. That may help us in solving your problem.

Comment: My bad.  error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::open(std::__cxx11::string&, const openmode&)'

Comment: this occurs at myFile.open(fileName, ios::out);

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look  at the error message, the first half of what is in the open parentheses tells you the answer. The user is typing in a char, the file name is expected to be a string. Instead of:

```
char fileName;
```

Use:

```
string fileName;
```